# Is it possible to simulate click using CGEvent for iOS app on Mac with M1?

Tags: swift, macos

I am trying to send click event to iOS-base app from App Store on ARM Mac(Apple Silicone, M1).

Here is snippet that works for any non-ios app:

```
import Foundation

func testClick(){
    let source = CGEventSource.init(stateID: .hidSystemState)
    let position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)
    let eventDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: position , mouseButton: .left)
    let eventUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: source, mouseType: .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: position , mouseButton: .left)
    eventDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
    usleep(500_000)
    eventUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
}
```

With any iOS-app this code will move cursor, but won't simulate click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the last Big Sur update this code works, but you need to focus window first time.

```
if(firstTime) testClick()
testClick()
```